How do I find an equivalent for this integral?
I am trying to derive concentration bounds for the spectral norm of some rank-one matrices under Gaussian measure. My objective is to obtain a bound with respect to both the number of samples $N$ and the dimension $n$ of the problem. However, when doing that, I stumble upon a term of the form
$$
\mathbb{E} \max_{t=1, \ldots, N} ||{X_t}||^2,
$$
where the $X_i$ are rank-one matrices with spectral norm equal to $||{X_t}||=\frac{1}{N}(\sum_{i=1}^n z_{t,i}^4 + 2\sum_{i<j} z_{t,i}^2 z_{t,j}^2 + n)$, and the $z_{t}=[z_{t,1}, \ldots, z_{t,n}]^{\top}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are i.i.d standard Gaussian variables, i.e., $z_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_n)$.
By trying to upper-bound this expectation, I came up with a complicated integral for which I need an equivalent.
My question is the following.
Let $$A(x) = \int_{x^2+x}^{\infty} u \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{u-x}-\sqrt{2x \sqrt{u-x}-x^2}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}u,$$
for $x\geq 0$. Then what is a equivalent of $A(x)$ as $x\to \infty$?
Edit:
Numerical experiments make me conjecture that $A(x)\sim Cx^4$ for some constant $C>0$.
I am also able to bound the expectation of the maximum by replacing the maximum by a sum of $N$ terms. By doing that, I obtain a not-so-bad bound which is essentially the same I would obtain with the equivalent $A(x)\sim Cx^4$. However, I am still curious.

After several (elementary) substitutions one finds
$$A(x) = x^4 \int_0^\infty (u+1) \left(u^2+2u+2\right) \left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{4} \left(u^2+2u+2\right)^2\right) \text{e}^{-\frac{x}{4}u^2}\,\text{d}u.$$
This can be solved exactly by using $\int_0^\infty u^n \text{e}^{-\frac{x}{4}u^2} = 2^n\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) x^{-(n+1)/2}$, and the leading order terms are
$$A(x) = x^4 \left[ \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{16}{x} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{-3/2}\right) \right].$$
Example: $x=1000$ gives an exact result of $1.30047\cdot 10^{11}$, while the leading term gives $1.12212\cdot 10^{11}$, and keeping the second one gives $1.28100\cdot 10^{11}$.

Why don't you give $$A(x)=2 \sqrt{\pi } x^{7/2}+16 x^3+32 \sqrt{\pi } x^{5/2}+144 x^2+156  \sqrt{\pi } x^{3/2}+392 x+210   \sqrt{\pi }   \sqrt{x}+192$$

Thanks. I suppose, I was a bit too lazy to type it out -- but you're right!
